# Difference of convergent sequences is positive: Prove or disprove

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose that, for $n=1,2,3,..$, two sequences of positive real numbers, $a_n$ and $b_n$, satisfy:

1: $a_{n+1}>a_n $ and $b_{n+1}>b_n$ ,$\forall n$ (In particular this implies $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to 0$ from above)

2: $ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n-b_n) < \infty  $

3: $\exists 1\le n_0$ such that $a_n-b_n>0$, $\forall n_0 \leq n$

Show that $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n-b_n)>0$

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that the sum is positive!

Comment: As in, what part don't you get? What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: I knew the first two conditions before deducing the third one, and now I'm trying to bound the first $n_0-1$ terms from below by a positive number. Nothing yet though. Do you have any hints perhaps ?

Comment: @user385459 "$a_{n+1} \gt a_n$" - did you mean the opposite inequality maybe? Otherwise "`this implies` $a_n \to 0$" doesn't hold.

Comment: Even if $a_{n+1} < a_n$ it still does not hold that $a_n \to 0$ necessarily.  But the opposite inequality is entirely incompatible with $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, since the conclusion need not hold.

For example, let
$$a_1 = 1,\;\;\;a_n = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\;\;\text{if}\;\,n>1$$
$$b_1 = 2,\;\;\;b_n = \frac{1}{2^n}\;\;\text{if}\;\,n>1$$